# Windows 8.1 XAML App, Embed Font with Multiple Files

Tags: xaml, fonts, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to embed a font contained across multiple files, as a single font.

I have the files 'MyriadPro-Bold.otf', 'MyriadPro-BoldCond.otf', 'MyriadPro-BoldCondIt.otf', etc. In my ResourceDictionary, I declare the FontFamily:

/Assets/Fonts/MyriadPro-Bold.otf

Obviously, I don't want to have a ton of FontFamily declarations, for each permutation of the MyriadPro font. What I want to know is - do I have to somehow find a way to compile the 10 otf files I have into a single one (tried FontSquirrel, no dice as MyriadPro is blacklisted), or is there some sort of magic I can use in xaml to combine them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I suspect the only way would be to wrap up the various odt files into a single file. Don't have to use this font any more, so no need to fix this problem.